# envoy container fails to start

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, containers, envoyproxy

envoy container failing while startup with the below error

```
Configuration does not parse cleanly as v3. v2 configuration is deprecated and will be removed from Envoy at the start of Q1 2021: Unknown field in: {"static_resources":{"listeners":[{"address":{"socket_address":{"address":"0.0.0.0","port_value":443}},"filter_chains":[{"tls_context":{"common_tls_context":{"tls_certificates":[{"private_key":{"filename":"/etc/ssl/private.key"},"certificate_chain":{"filename":"/etc/ssl/keychain.crt"}}]}},"filters":[{"typed_config":{"route_config":{"name":"local_route","virtual_hosts":[{"domains":["*"],"routes":[{"match":{"prefix":"/"},"route":{"host_rewrite_literal":"127.0.0.1","cluster":"service_envoyproxy_io"}}],"name":"local_service"}]},"@type":"type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager","http_filters":[{"name":"envoy.filters.http.router"}],"access_log":[{"typed_config":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog","path":"/dev/stdout"},"name":"envoy.access_loggers.file"}],"stat_prefix":"ingress_http"},"name":"envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"}]}],"name":"listener_0"}],"clusters":[{"load_assignment":{"cluster_name":"service_envoyproxy_io","endpoints":[{"lb_endpoints":[{"endpoint":{"address":{"socket_address":{"port_value":8080,"address":"127.0.0.1"}}}}]}]},"connect_timeout":"30s","name":"service_envoyproxy_io","dns_lookup_family":"V4_ONLY","transport_socket":{"name":"envoy.transport_sockets.tls","typed_config":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext","sni":"www.envoyproxy.io"}},"type":"LOGICAL_DNS"}]}}
```

Here's my envoy.yaml file

```
static_resources:

  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 443
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
              path: /dev/stdout
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  host_rewrite_literal: 127.0.0.1
                  cluster: service_envoyproxy_io
      tls_context:
        common_tls_context:
          tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: "/etc/ssl/keychain.crt"
              private_key:
                filename: "/etc/ssl/private.key"

  clusters:
  - name: service_envoyproxy_io
    connect_timeout: 30s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service_envoyproxy_io
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 8080
    transport_socket:
      name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
      typed_config:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
        sni: www.envoyproxy.io
```

I'm I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that: `Configuration does not parse cleanly as v3. v2 configuration is deprecated and will be removed from Envoy at the start of Q1 2021`. The v2 xDS APIs are deprecated and will be removed form Envoy in Q1 2021, as per the [API versioning policy](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/a52ec8b4146dc7db630cd5372fb714f104e1f740//api/API_VERSIONING.md).

According to the official docs you got the following options:

1. In the interim, you can continue to use the v2 API for the transitional period by:

- Setting `--bootstrap-version` 2 on the CLI for a v2 bootstrap file.
- Enabling the runtime *envoy.reloadable_features.enable_deprecated_v2_api* feature. This is implicitly enabled if a v2 `--bootstrap-version` is set.

2. Or [Configure Envoy to use the v3 API](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/faq/api/envoy_v3#how-do-i-configure-envoy-to-use-the-v3-api)

More details can be found in the linked docs.

Comment: Wiktor Do I need to make these changes in envoy.yaml?

Comment: No, `--bootstrap-version` it's a command line option, [see here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/cli#cmdoption-bootstrap-version). Bear in mind that the 2nd option from my answer would help you configure Envoy to not use the deprecated v2 API which overall is the more recommended approach.